# How to obtain an application snapshot at changeset from TFS?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm on a new machine and I connected to my team project in TFS using Visual Studio 2015.  However I don't want to map and get latest.  I want to map and get the application as it looked at a particular changeset and continue working from that.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved. Do not use **map&get** together in team explorer. You can do it separately in solution explorer. First map the workspace, and then get the specific version. Detail steps please refer my screenshot below:

1. *Map the workspace and **not select get now***

[image]

*2. Get specific version*

[image]

*3. Select changest*
[image]